# Post Multiple Events within One HttpRequest to Google Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

Is there a way, server-side using .NET, to send multiple custom events to Google Analytics with one HTTP Request?  We may need to send multiple requests within one Controller action, yet we want to avoid the overhead of many HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Google Analytics transmits data via GET or POST requests to `google-analytics.com/__utm.gif`; each request is treated as one hit, and there is no way to combine multiple data points into a single request.