# Track multiple events with Global Site Tag

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible with Global Site Tag to track multiple events in a single http request? For example, the following codes generates 3 calls to the google tracking server, if possible i would like to make only 1 call.

```
gtag('event', 'Views', {'event_category':'Company', 'event_label': 'a','value':1,'non_interaction': true});
        gtag('event', 'Views', {'event_category':'Company', 'event_label': 'b','value':1,'non_interaction': true});
        gtag('event', 'Views', {'event_category':'Company', 'event_label': 'c','value':1,'non_interaction': true});
```

The following question is very similar:
[Google Analytics - track multiple events in single HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360227/google-analytics-track-multiple-events-in-single-http-request)
But this question is about Universal Analytics, my question is about newer Global Site Tag.